# Optimization multilingual site with the same address for each language

Tags: php

How do I change the title and description that appears when you search my site on google based on the browser language of the visitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the

```
$browserlocale = locale_accept_from_http( $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );
$language = substr($browserlocale, 2);
```

to get the *prefered language* from the browser.

Having said that, from there on you can use the [gettext extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) to localize your app. There is a [nice editor](http://www.poedit.net/) for translating gettext strings.

You have to tell google that your site is multilingual. You do that by [providing a sitemap.xml to the google bot](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184).